# Get address of a multidimensional static array

Tags: c, arrays

How can I get the address of a multidimensional static array?
For example, this is my array

```
char array[2][10] = {"word1", "word2"};
```

Is it possible to get the address to make me reference this array using a pointer like this?

```
char** pointer;
```

I tried &array or directly pointer = (char**)array; but it crashes at startup.

Comment: `char** pointer = array` is sufficient. If it crashes, you have bug somewhere else. You don't even need a cast.

Comment: post your code. `pointer=(char**)array;` should have worked, if it's crashing - there's some other problem.

Comment: Uhm it's crashing because I'm referencing 2nd char* (word2) with "pointer[0]"... Instead using just "pointer" all chars until '\0' is printed thus I see "word1". But why is illegal? char** pointer should be an array of char*, so this expression "pointer[0]" shouldn't be illegal...

Comment: read section 6 of [the c-faq](http://c-faq.com): **arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.**

Comment: Thanks I knew the difference... Unluckily I left C for too much time to Java, and these are the things you've not to worry about using Java. You think only "every reference is a pointer" :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char **pointer` means that a pointer is pointing to a pointer.
So `*pointer` is expected to be a pointer (e.g. 4-byte value which can be interpreted as an address).

This is not the case with your array: it is a contiguous area in memory (20 bytes).

So when you try to convert the array to `char **` your application crashes.
It's not possible to do this conversion, `char **` must point at a pointer.

Comment: And credit to "Expert C Programming" by Peter Van Der Linden who explained so many things I thought I already knew.

Comment: Right... "array" can be seen as a simple char* pointer treated as a "bounded" matrix by the compiler. Thus I will get in error assigning this array to an array of pointers. I should initialize every pointer by my self, doing like this? `
 char arr[2][20] = {"word1","word2"};
 char **pointer = new char*[2];
 pointer[0] = arr[0];
 pointer[1] = arr[1];`

Comment: @Exor: Yes, that would work. But it has to be done "manually", there is no automatic conversion, because the types are incompatible.

Answer (score 2):

"array" is the address of the array in memory but it is not a char**. While you can cast it, the application will crash if you try

```
printf("%s", pointer[1]);
```

because in your case is probably the same as

```
printf("%s", (char *)(0x00000031));
```

since pointer[1] means "the second 4 byte pointer (assuming x86) starting from 'array'".
pointer[0] MAY not crash but won't show "word1" either for the same reason.

You probably want (this is hard to remeber so i had to check online, hope it is correct):

```
char (*pointer)[10] = array;
```

Which is a pointer to an array of 10 chars. And if you use pointer[1] it now means "the second 10 chars block starting from 'array'".